# Neo4j Syntax error Unknown function 'date'

Tags: function, date, neo4j, cypher, temporal

Freshly installed community Neo4j desktop 3.5. Trying to run

```
RETURN date();
```

throws exception

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Unknown function 'date' (line 1, column 16 (offset: 15))
"return date()"
```

Added APOC and ALGO libraries, so now I can run successfully something like that:

```
apoc.date.currentTimestamp()
```

Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Unknown function 'date' 
Was trying to run exercise 7.4 of the Tutorial, sample solution code is failing with the same error.

Comment: Possibly a bug in your version. Try installing the latest version (3.5.9).

Comment: Community edition 3.5.11 definitely resolved the issue. Hope the Desktop distribution will be updated too.